# Install Epson AcuLaser on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, printer, printing

I am a newbie regarding Ubuntu, and I have installed a PC for playing around and testing it.
The problem is that the  Epson printer I have (AcuLaser CX11NF, a network/usb color laser with fax & scanner) does not seem to be supported by Ubuntu nor by Epson (for Linux).
Anyone has a link or suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epson does in fact offer [Linux printer drivers for the AcuLaser CX11NF](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=58603&prodoid=58311371&infoType=Downloads&platform=Other). I've had bad experience with Avasys drivers, but for this model it seems that you have no choice, and there are [success](http://www.gedda.info/?p=132) [reports](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=156631) for your model and distribution.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, but *gee* that's so complicated. They ask if i want to get Suse or Fedora, if I wwant to print via CUPS or LPRng. I have no cue. Here is the link, if someone else needs it: http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/mfp/DL2.do

Comment: For the scanner, I found I have to use Debian, for Ubuntu. But for the printer, I am lost.

Comment: @iDevlop: Welcome to the wonderful world of proprietary software... Ubuntu is closest to Debian, and uses CUPS.